What dependencies does Pandoc-generated latex require?
I have this markdown that I'd like to \include{} in a larger latex document.
$ cat example.md
# heading

- Item 1
- Item 2

```bash
Code block
```

If I run that through pandoc 2.9.2.1 (Debian 11) I get this:
$ pandoc -t latex example.md
\begin{itemize}
\tightlist
\item
  Item 1
\item
  Item 2
\end{itemize}

\begin{Shaded}
\begin{Highlighting}[]
\ExtensionTok{Code}\NormalTok{ block}
\end{Highlighting}
\end{Shaded}

Now I just need to \include{} it in my main document:
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}

% Autogenerated from markdown with `pandoc example.md -o example.tex`
\include{example.tex}

\end{document}


It would be wonderful if that's all I needed.  But that compiles  in:
! Undefined control sequence.
l.1 \hypertarget
                {heading}{%


No problem.  I recognize that command.   I can just add \usepackage{hyperref} to the preamble:
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\begin{document}

% Autogenerated from markdown with `pandoc example.md -o example.tex`
\include{example.tex}

\end{document}

! Undefined control sequence.
l.5 \tightlist


A bit tougher.  I don't recognize that macro.  But I did some searching and found what it's supposed to do, so I can make my own implementation.
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\providecommand{\tightlist}{\setlength{\itemsep}{0pt}\setlength{\parskip}{0pt}}

\begin{document}

% Autogenerated from markdown with `pandoc example.md -o example.tex`
\include{example.tex}

\end{document}

! LaTeX Error: Environment Shaded undefined.
l.12 \begin{Shaded}


Getting even tougher.  In texlive there is a package framed which provides environment shaded, so let's try that:
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{framed}

\providecommand{\tightlist}{\setlength{\itemsep}{0pt}\setlength{\parskip}{0pt}}
\newenvironment{Shaded}{\begin{shaded}}{\end{shaded}} 

\begin{document}

% Autogenerated from markdown with `pandoc example.md -o example.tex`
\include{example.tex}

\end{document}

! Undefined control sequence.
\FrameCommand ->\fboxsep =\FrameSep \colorbox 
                                              {shadecolor}
l.12 \begin{Shaded}


Okay, so I need to defined a colour.  I recognize that from xcolor
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{framed}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\providecommand{\tightlist}{\setlength{\itemsep}{0pt}\setlength{\parskip}{0pt}}
\newenvironment{Shaded}{\begin{shaded}}{\end{shaded}}
\definecolor{shadecolor}{rgb}{1.0, 1.0, 0.95}

\begin{document}

\include{example.tex}
\end{document}

! LaTeX Error: Environment Highlighting undefined.
l.13 \begin{Highlighting}
                         []


This seems like it's getting too deep.  Everytime a user submits a new markdown to me, they seem to trigger another macro that I haven't implemented yet.  Is there a single \usepackage{...} in the texlive distribution that I can bring in to define all of this for me?  I feel like pandoc didn't intend for me to re-implement everything using my best guesses.
The debian packages I have installed are:
$ dpkg -l | grep texlive | awk '{print $2}'
texlive
texlive-base
texlive-binaries
texlive-font-utils
texlive-fonts-extra
texlive-fonts-extra-links
texlive-fonts-recommended
texlive-latex-base
texlive-latex-extra
texlive-latex-recommended
texlive-luatex
texlive-pictures
texlive-plain-generic


Are all dependencies included if you invoke pandoc with the -s option (for a "standalone" document)?

Oh, I had never seen the -s option.  I wouldn't normally use it anyways, since the markdowns tend to be snippets in larger documents.  That does provide the things I need. Thanks

Thanks to @Heiko Theißen's comment, pandoc has a -s option to generate a stand-alone tex file.  Here's what you need (wish they would have purged the subjective style stuff and provided the rest in an sty).  The only trick is the first two lines go above your \documentclass{}:
\PassOptionsToPackage{unicode}{hyperref}
\PassOptionsToPackage{hyphens}{url}

\documentclass{...}

\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage{amssymb,amsmath}
\usepackage{ifxetex,ifluatex}
\ifnum 0\ifxetex 1\fi\ifluatex 1\fi=0
  \usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
  \usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
  \usepackage{textcomp}
\else
  \usepackage{unicode-math}
  \defaultfontfeatures{Scale=MatchLowercase}
  \defaultfontfeatures[\rmfamily]{Ligatures=TeX,Scale=1}
\fi
\IfFileExists{upquote.sty}{\usepackage{upquote}}{}
\IfFileExists{microtype.sty}{
  \usepackage[]{microtype}
  \UseMicrotypeSet[protrusion]{basicmath}
}{}
\makeatletter
\@ifundefined{KOMAClassName}{
  \IfFileExists{parskip.sty}{%
    \usepackage{parskip}
  }{
    \setlength{\parindent}{0pt}
    \setlength{\parskip}{6pt plus 2pt minus 1pt}}
}{
  \KOMAoptions{parskip=half}}
\makeatother
\usepackage{xcolor}
\IfFileExists{xurl.sty}{\usepackage{xurl}}{}
\IfFileExists{bookmark.sty}{\usepackage{bookmark}}{\usepackage{hyperref}}
\usepackage{color}
\usepackage{fancyvrb}
\newcommand{\VerbBar}{|}
\newcommand{\VERB}{\Verb[commandchars=\\\{\}]}
\DefineVerbatimEnvironment{Highlighting}{Verbatim}{commandchars=\\\{\}}
\newenvironment{Shaded}{}{}
\newcommand{\AlertTok}[1]{\textcolor[rgb]{1.00,0.00,0.00}{\textbf{#1}}}
\newcommand{\AnnotationTok}[1]{\textcolor[rgb]{0.38,0.63,0.69}{\textbf{\textit{#1}}}}
\newcommand{\AttributeTok}[1]{\textcolor[rgb]{0.49,0.56,0.16}{#1}}
\newcommand{\BaseNTok}[1]{\textcolor[rgb]{0.25,0.63,0.44}{#1}}
\newcommand{\BuiltInTok}[1]{#1}
\newcommand{\CharTok}[1]{\textcolor[rgb]{0.25,0.44,0.63}{#1}}
\newcommand{\CommentTok}[1]{\textcolor[rgb]{0.38,0.63,0.69}{\textit{#1}}}
\newcommand{\CommentVarTok}[1]{\textcolor[rgb]{0.38,0.63,0.69}{\textbf{\textit{#1}}}}
\newcommand{\ConstantTok}[1]{\textcolor[rgb]{0.53,0.00,0.00}{#1}}
\newcommand{\ControlFlowTok}[1]{\textcolor[rgb]{0.00,0.44,0.13}{\textbf{#1}}}
\newcommand{\DataTypeTok}[1]{\textcolor[rgb]{0.56,0.13,0.00}{#1}}
\newcommand{\DecValTok}[1]{\textcolor[rgb]{0.25,0.63,0.44}{#1}}
\newcommand{\DocumentationTok}[1]{\textcolor[rgb]{0.73,0.13,0.13}{\textit{#1}}}
\newcommand{\ErrorTok}[1]{\textcolor[rgb]{1.00,0.00,0.00}{\textbf{#1}}}
\newcommand{\ExtensionTok}[1]{#1}
\newcommand{\FloatTok}[1]{\textcolor[rgb]{0.25,0.63,0.44}{#1}}
\newcommand{\FunctionTok}[1]{\textcolor[rgb]{0.02,0.16,0.49}{#1}}
\newcommand{\ImportTok}[1]{#1}
\newcommand{\InformationTok}[1]{\textcolor[rgb]{0.38,0.63,0.69}{\textbf{\textit{#1}}}}
\newcommand{\KeywordTok}[1]{\textcolor[rgb]{0.00,0.44,0.13}{\textbf{#1}}}
\newcommand{\NormalTok}[1]{#1}
\newcommand{\OperatorTok}[1]{\textcolor[rgb]{0.40,0.40,0.40}{#1}}
\newcommand{\OtherTok}[1]{\textcolor[rgb]{0.00,0.44,0.13}{#1}}
\newcommand{\PreprocessorTok}[1]{\textcolor[rgb]{0.74,0.48,0.00}{#1}}
\newcommand{\RegionMarkerTok}[1]{#1}
\newcommand{\SpecialCharTok}[1]{\textcolor[rgb]{0.25,0.44,0.63}{#1}}
\newcommand{\SpecialStringTok}[1]{\textcolor[rgb]{0.73,0.40,0.53}{#1}}
\newcommand{\StringTok}[1]{\textcolor[rgb]{0.25,0.44,0.63}{#1}}
\newcommand{\VariableTok}[1]{\textcolor[rgb]{0.10,0.09,0.49}{#1}}
\newcommand{\VerbatimStringTok}[1]{\textcolor[rgb]{0.25,0.44,0.63}{#1}}
\newcommand{\WarningTok}[1]{\textcolor[rgb]{0.38,0.63,0.69}{\textbf{\textit{#1}}}}
\providecommand{\tightlist}{\setlength{\itemsep}{0pt}\setlength{\parskip}{0pt}}


FYI, this is the fully-generated stand-alone tex file:
% Options for packages loaded elsewhere
\PassOptionsToPackage{unicode}{hyperref}
\PassOptionsToPackage{hyphens}{url}
%
\documentclass[
]{article}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage{amssymb,amsmath}
\usepackage{ifxetex,ifluatex}
\ifnum 0\ifxetex 1\fi\ifluatex 1\fi=0 % if pdftex
  \usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
  \usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
  \usepackage{textcomp} % provide euro and other symbols
\else % if luatex or xetex
  \usepackage{unicode-math}
  \defaultfontfeatures{Scale=MatchLowercase}
  \defaultfontfeatures[\rmfamily]{Ligatures=TeX,Scale=1}
\fi
% Use upquote if available, for straight quotes in verbatim environments
\IfFileExists{upquote.sty}{\usepackage{upquote}}{}
\IfFileExists{microtype.sty}{% use microtype if available
  \usepackage[]{microtype}
  \UseMicrotypeSet[protrusion]{basicmath} % disable protrusion for tt fonts
}{}
\makeatletter
\@ifundefined{KOMAClassName}{% if non-KOMA class
  \IfFileExists{parskip.sty}{%
    \usepackage{parskip}
  }{% else
    \setlength{\parindent}{0pt}
    \setlength{\parskip}{6pt plus 2pt minus 1pt}}
}{% if KOMA class
  \KOMAoptions{parskip=half}}
\makeatother
\usepackage{xcolor}
\IfFileExists{xurl.sty}{\usepackage{xurl}}{} % add URL line breaks if available
\IfFileExists{bookmark.sty}{\usepackage{bookmark}}{\usepackage{hyperref}}
\hypersetup{
  hidelinks,
  pdfcreator={LaTeX via pandoc}}
\urlstyle{same} % disable monospaced font for URLs
\usepackage{color}
\usepackage{fancyvrb}
\newcommand{\VerbBar}{|}
\newcommand{\VERB}{\Verb[commandchars=\\\{\}]}
\DefineVerbatimEnvironment{Highlighting}{Verbatim}{commandchars=\\\{\}}
% Add ',fontsize=\small' for more characters per line
\newenvironment{Shaded}{}{}
\newcommand{\AlertTok}[1]{\textcolor[rgb]{1.00,0.00,0.00}{\textbf{#1}}}
\newcommand{\AnnotationTok}[1]{\textcolor[rgb]{0.38,0.63,0.69}{\textbf{\textit{#1}}}}
\newcommand{\AttributeTok}[1]{\textcolor[rgb]{0.49,0.56,0.16}{#1}}
\newcommand{\BaseNTok}[1]{\textcolor[rgb]{0.25,0.63,0.44}{#1}}
\newcommand{\BuiltInTok}[1]{#1}
\newcommand{\CharTok}[1]{\textcolor[rgb]{0.25,0.44,0.63}{#1}}
\newcommand{\CommentTok}[1]{\textcolor[rgb]{0.38,0.63,0.69}{\textit{#1}}}
\newcommand{\CommentVarTok}[1]{\textcolor[rgb]{0.38,0.63,0.69}{\textbf{\textit{#1}}}}
\newcommand{\ConstantTok}[1]{\textcolor[rgb]{0.53,0.00,0.00}{#1}}
\newcommand{\ControlFlowTok}[1]{\textcolor[rgb]{0.00,0.44,0.13}{\textbf{#1}}}
\newcommand{\DataTypeTok}[1]{\textcolor[rgb]{0.56,0.13,0.00}{#1}}
\newcommand{\DecValTok}[1]{\textcolor[rgb]{0.25,0.63,0.44}{#1}}
\newcommand{\DocumentationTok}[1]{\textcolor[rgb]{0.73,0.13,0.13}{\textit{#1}}}
\newcommand{\ErrorTok}[1]{\textcolor[rgb]{1.00,0.00,0.00}{\textbf{#1}}}
\newcommand{\ExtensionTok}[1]{#1}
\newcommand{\FloatTok}[1]{\textcolor[rgb]{0.25,0.63,0.44}{#1}}
\newcommand{\FunctionTok}[1]{\textcolor[rgb]{0.02,0.16,0.49}{#1}}
\newcommand{\ImportTok}[1]{#1}
\newcommand{\InformationTok}[1]{\textcolor[rgb]{0.38,0.63,0.69}{\textbf{\textit{#1}}}}
\newcommand{\KeywordTok}[1]{\textcolor[rgb]{0.00,0.44,0.13}{\textbf{#1}}}
\newcommand{\NormalTok}[1]{#1}
\newcommand{\OperatorTok}[1]{\textcolor[rgb]{0.40,0.40,0.40}{#1}}
\newcommand{\OtherTok}[1]{\textcolor[rgb]{0.00,0.44,0.13}{#1}}
\newcommand{\PreprocessorTok}[1]{\textcolor[rgb]{0.74,0.48,0.00}{#1}}
\newcommand{\RegionMarkerTok}[1]{#1}
\newcommand{\SpecialCharTok}[1]{\textcolor[rgb]{0.25,0.44,0.63}{#1}}
\newcommand{\SpecialStringTok}[1]{\textcolor[rgb]{0.73,0.40,0.53}{#1}}
\newcommand{\StringTok}[1]{\textcolor[rgb]{0.25,0.44,0.63}{#1}}
\newcommand{\VariableTok}[1]{\textcolor[rgb]{0.10,0.09,0.49}{#1}}
\newcommand{\VerbatimStringTok}[1]{\textcolor[rgb]{0.25,0.44,0.63}{#1}}
\newcommand{\WarningTok}[1]{\textcolor[rgb]{0.38,0.63,0.69}{\textbf{\textit{#1}}}}
\setlength{\emergencystretch}{3em} % prevent overfull lines
\providecommand{\tightlist}{%
  \setlength{\itemsep}{0pt}\setlength{\parskip}{0pt}}
\setcounter{secnumdepth}{-\maxdimen} % remove section numbering

\author{}
\date{}

\begin{document}

\hypertarget{heading}{%
\section{heading}\label{heading}}

\begin{itemize}
\tightlist
\item
  Item 1
\item
  Item 2
\end{itemize}

\begin{Shaded}
\begin{Highlighting}[]
\ExtensionTok{Code}\NormalTok{ block}
\end{Highlighting}
\end{Shaded}


\end{document}

